# How to decrypt text that was encrypted using RSA in C#

Tags: c#, php, rsa, phpseclib

I need to convert code from C# to PHP, with identical results.
In C# I finished it pretty quickly, but now need to convert the following code to php:

```
public static string RsaDecrypt(string privateKey, string src)
{
    CspParameters csp = new CspParameters();
    csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
    return RsaDecrypt(rsa, src);
}

public static string RsaDecrypt(RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa, string src)
{
    byte[] srcData = Convert.FromBase64String(src);
    byte[] destData = rsa.Decrypt(srcData, false);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(destData);
}
```

I'm trying to hours and I can not, I'm using the [phpseclib0.2.1a](http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/phpseclib/phpseclib0.2.1a.zip) file and the code:

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hWWm47GV)

The Problem in PHP is returning the following error:

> **Notice**: Decryption error in E:\AppServWWW\Request\Flash\Crypt\RSA.php on line 1582

**@EDIT**: My $_GET["p"] is

> cwQPQLSW%2FQ70AUmBzkZ9c7d9MrEAcPAAN1lRG937XZuibDOE304i8894uowlC1OANnWEim6suOxzhEHZl0BR1G1audk4CWG1TUSqAo4MO5FBfVbmcLVMx1KPV9%2FeMzil%2BHM1XwyX3Dm0h%2F0uAxORfpa3waq0iOemkUYBq2lXDEU%3D

Comment: Also, please tell us which line is 1582......

Comment: if ($lHash != $lHash2) {
            user_error('Decryption error', E_USER_NOTICE);
            return false;
        }

Comment: 1) You didn't post your encryption code. 2) Setting the second parameter of `Decrypt` to `false` means you're using a bad padding. 3) Consider encrypting the actual data with AES and only encrypting the key with RSA. RSA should only be used to encrypt short data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of phpseclib is 0.3.1 so, first, I'd recommend you upgrade.

Second... phpseclib does OAEP padding by default. C# is probably doing PKCS1 padding by default. So you'd need to do `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);` before doing the actual decryption in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, the code worked as it should.
Updated my phpseclib and added your code and it worked =]
Thank you very much.

Comment: That's exactly the wrong way round. You should use OAEP for both, not PKCS#1v1.5. The older padding scheme is flawed and allows padding-oracle attacks.